# Mockito - mocking POST request - ParameterizedTypeReference.forType(String.class

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am attempting to create a unit test where a post request is being made.

`WebClient.post(URI, request, ParameterizedTypeReference.forType(String.class));`

I am trying to use `Mockit.when(WebClient.post(Mockito.anyString(), null, Mockito.eq(new ParameterizedTypeReference<String> {})).thenReturn(nothing);`

I am getting

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:ParameterizedTypeReference must not be null`

How can I correctly mock this `ParameterizedTypeReference.forType(String.class)`?

Comment: Where/how do you create the mock object for `WebClient`?

Comment: the WebClient is created as static. it is an import from an external jar

Comment: if it is not a mock instance (created with `@Mock` or `Mockito.mock`), then you cannot set up stubbings on it (with `Mockito.when`). It's not a mock, thus cannot be used as one.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to passing a null value to the `ParameterizedTypeReference.forType` method.

```
@Test
void test() {
//Initialise uri, request 
ParameterizedTypeReference < String > response = ParameterizedTypeReference.forType(String.class);
String returnValue = “response”;
when(webClient.post().uri(uri).bodyValue(request).retrieve().bodyToMono(any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class)))
.thenReturn(Mono.just(returnValue));
 String result = mockClass.postMethod(uri, request, response);
 assertEquals(returnValue, result);
 }
```

Comment: no this does not work